# Does it make sense to define a "metric topological space" $(M, d, \tau)$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, soft-question, metric-spaces, compactness

When doing things related to compactness, sometimes you have to switch definition from sequential compactness which is defined on a metric space $(M, d)$, to things related to covering compactness which is defined on $(M, \tau)$ (or $(M,d)$?)

I find it troublesome to switch between "Let $A \subset (M, \tau)$" and "let $A \subset (M, d)$ ". Why don't we simulatenously work in both spaces. Then I remembered that a metric $d$ is not a topology, and $\tau$ is not a metric. So is it possible to define this triple $(M, d, \tau)$? If so it usual to do so?

Comment: If we wanted to be pedantic, we could write (M,d,T) but it is customary that when we refer to the metric space (M,d), that it is assumed to have  the topology generated by d. And also customary to speak of a space S  when we mean a set S with a topology T on it.These are examples of what is called "the usual abuse of notation."

Comment: I want to be that crank

Comment: No problem.But you will  have to define what you mean by (M,d,T) almost every time, as others will not be accustomed to it.

Comment: I would not advise writing either $A \subset (M,\tau)$ or $A \subset (M,d)$. Just write $A \subset M$, it is the only thing that makes set-theoretic sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both sequential and covering compactness are purely topological notions. Moreover, if the metric $d$ induces the topology $\tau$ then there is no confusion.

Comment: My professor always told us that sequential compactness and covering compactness coincides on metric spaces so I just assumed sequential compactness was purely metric notion...

Comment: They are both topological notions, but in general they do not coincide. There are spaces which can be sequentially compact but not covering compact, and vice-versa. However, for metric spaces they are the same.

In any event, sequential compactness is just about covergence of sequences, it doesn't require us to define a metric.

Answer (score 2):

You can define $(M,d)$ to be a metric space and let $\tau$ be the induced topology on $M$, but $(M,d)$ suffices for common purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Unless specified otherwise, one usually associates the topology which is induced by the metric. That means if we have a metric space $(M,d)$, one implicitely views this as the topological space $(M,\tau)$ (if needed), where $\tau$ is the topology induced by the metric $d$, i.e. $\tau = \{U(x,r),:x\in M, r>0\}$ where $U(x,r)=\{y\in M: d(x,y)<r\}$.

The same is true for stronger structures than the metric, i.e. one views the normed space $(M,\|\cdot\|)$ as the metric space where $d(x,y)=\|x-y\|$ and the inner procuct space $(M, \langle \cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ as the normed space where $\|x\|=\sqrt{\langle x ,x \rangle}$.